# Como puedo listar solo las ordenes de ciertos años MySql Base de Datos Northwind, Tabla orders

Tags: mysql, sql

Por favor quisiera mostrar el código de la orden, código de cliente, código de empleado y año de la orden y nombre del día de la semana, de todas las órdenes realizadas los lunes durante los años 1994 y 1996, por el empleado del código N° 6

Estoy trabajando con la Base de Datos Northwind

Tengo esta sintaxis:

```
Select OrderID, 
            CustomerID, 
            EmployeeID,
            OrderDate
from orders
```

Mis preguntas son:

- ¿Cómo puedo colocar en el campo `employeeId` que sea solo igual a 6?
- En el campo `yearOfOrder` solo los años 1994y 1996
- El día solo tipo texto.

Espero poder listar los datos de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de:

- `WHERE IN` que va a verificar si un valor es igual a alguna de las condiciones, pero no las 2 a la vez
- Hacemos uso de `AND` para poder indicar que a parte de la condición anterior debe cumplir la condición de que el id del empleado sea igual a 6.
- Tu última condición para verificar solo aquellos registros en día lunes, debe ir dicho valor entre comillas puesto que es una cadena de texto

Prueba de este modo:

```
Select OrderID,
       CustomerID, 
       EmployeeID, 
       OrderDate 
from orders
WHERE yearOfOrder IN(1994, 1996)
AND employeeId = 6
AND dayName = "Monday";
```

Comment: Super, perfecto mil gracias.